# Python using append returns multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am struggling to write/append a dictionary to a text file. Using 'a' my dictionary has the form{'word_one:'definition_one'}{'word_two:'definition_two'}… instead of what I thought I would get ( and wanted) {'word_one:'definition_one','word_two:'definition_two'…}. What am I doing wrongly. Sorry for such a basic question. I thought that I understood dictionaries and writing to text files, but…
The code is:

```
import ast
import operator

def collectDict():

     # first initialize your final_dict and dante_dict dictionary
     final_dict={}
     with open('/Users/admin/Desktop/Dante Dictionary/experimental_dict.txt','r', encoding = "utf-8") as dic:
             dante_dict = ast.literal_eval(dic.read())# reads text as a dictionary


     (dante_dict,final_dict) = define_words(dante_dict,final_dict)    # call the define_words function to update your dictionaries


     # write your dictionaries

     with open('/Users/admin/Desktop/Dante Dictionary/experimental_dict.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as outfile:
             outfile.write(str(dante_dict)) # writes source dictionary minus newly-defined term

     with open('/Users/admin/Desktop/Dante Dictionary/trial_dictionary.txt', 'a', encoding = 'utf-8') as finalfile:
             finalfile.write(str(final_dict)) 
     with open('/Users/admin/Desktop/Dante Dictionary/trial_dictionary.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as finalfile:
          prelim_dict = ast.literal_eval(finalfile.read())
          print(prelim_dict)


def define_words(dante_dict,final_dict):
   # your already written function without the initialization (first 3 lines) and file writing part
   print('There were ', len(dante_dict), ' entries before defining this word') 
   key_to_find = max(dante_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
   print('The next word to define is ', key_to_find) # show which word needs defining

   definition = input('Definition ? : ') # prompt for definition
   final_dict = {}

   if key_to_find in dante_dict:
       final_dict.append[key_to_find] = definition
       del dante_dict[key_to_find] # remove entry from source dictionary once new definition is done
   print('the end length is : ' ,len(dante_dict)) # check that entry has been removed from source

   return(dante_dict,final_dict)  # you return the dictionaries for the other function
```

The text file that I start with is :

```
{'amico   ': 1, "'Segnor": 1, 'volgere': 1, 'spaventate,': 1, "s'avvantaggia": 1, 'livore': 1, 'disposta   ': 1, 'pennelli': 1, 'atto': 15, 'Berti': 1, 'atti': 7, 'Gaia    ': 1, 'alzato,': 1, 'reda': 2, "d'ossa": 1, 'rede': 1, 'solvesi': 1, 'Dopo': 3, 'amico,': 1, 'Sardi,': 1, 'pastore,': 2, 'sana   ': 1,…}
```

Comment: [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) is the tool for this task.

Answer (score 1):

`final_dict` is a **list** of dictionaries, not one dictionary. By using `list.append()` you keep adding new dictionaries to that list.

Make it a dictionary instead, then assign to keys on that dictionary:

```
final_dict = {}

if key_to_find in dante_dict:
    final_dict[key_to_find] = definition
    del dante_dict[key_to_find]
```

Note that there is no point in looping over the whole `dante_dict` keys to see if a key is in it when you can just use `key in dict`, a much faster method. The `del dict[key]` expression at the end replaces the `dante_dict.pop()` expression in your code.

Comment: Thank you for being so patient with me. I now get dict object has no method append. Should I use update or what have I done wrong yet again?

Comment: @user1478335: Oops, no, that was a copy-and-paste error on my part. The `.append` is not needed here.